# Writing discord auto send messages

Tags: python, discord.py, schedule

I need to send messages at specific time in discord chat.

I use both `discord` and `schedule` module

[base code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLkrM.png).
I use the function send_schedule_message to send the message. from a list called schedule_messages, I parse the time and message I want to send. However, nothing is happening at the said time without errors.

schedule_messages = {
        "11:55": "Mine Clearence",
        "19:55": "Golemore",
        "01:49": "Daily reset"
    }

```
async def send_scheduled_message(message):
    channel_id = 1160338542329860116  
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    if channel is not None:
        await channel.send(message)
    else:
        print(f"Channel with ID {channel_id} not found.")

for time_str, message in schedule_messages.items():
    schedule.every().day.at(time_str, timezone('Europe/London')).do(asyncio.run, send_scheduled_message, message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while True:` loop at the end will not be run because the `client.run` will not return. It will hang until the bot disconnects.

You can use `discord.ext.tasks` which is the official way of running background tasks.

The [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) gives details on how to use a `Cog` approach. Since you seem to be using `discord.Client` rather than `discord.ext.commands.Bot`, you probably want to do something like this:

```py
import asyncio
import schedule
from discord import Client, Intents
from discord.ext import tasks

client = Client(intents=Intents.all())

async def send_scheduled_message(message):
    channel_id = 1160338542329860116
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id) or await client.fetch_channel(channel_id)
    if channel is not None:
        await channel.send(message)
    else:
        print(f"Channel with ID {channel_id} not found.")

def run_async(coro, *args):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.create_task(coro(*args))

# replace with your schedules
schedule.every().second.do(run_async, send_scheduled_message, 'test this')

@tasks.loop(seconds=1.0)
async def loop():
    schedule.run_pending()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Starting schedule loop.')
    try:
        loop.start()
    except RuntimeError:
        # loop already started
        pass

client.run('...')
```

The `run_async` function is required because you cannot call `asyncio.run` when an event loop is already started by discord.py. It gets the current event loop and runs `send_scheduled_message` inside it.

The `loop` function is the loop managed by discord.py. It's started in `on_ready`.